# RESTful API: require user agent string?

Tags: rest, user-agent

My team has a web site with a RESTful API.  We're is working on load testing it, so we've built a small console app to hammer it with requests.  This console app does not set the user agent string, and that is causing an error in our API because it is a required field in our database.

So, should I make the API extra robust and simply use a default string (i.e. "unknown") if a user agent isn't included in the request?  Or, should I return a 400 Bad Request response in this situation?  I know either is possible, but I'm looking for the *standard* way to do this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since the `User-Agent` header is not absolutely required to be present within HTTP requests (the [spec says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43) the header `SHOULD` be there, rather than `MUST`), your API would be more robust if it could handle it not being present.

That said, it would probably be good for your test app to pass a `User-Agent` identifier of "test app" or something, just so you could track it in your database, or to throttle or profile your test traffic.

I would caution you not to use `User-Agent` as a definitive identifier of the client application though, since it is so easily spoofed. It doesn't sound like you're doing that but I thought I'd mention it.