# REST API in PHP - anauthorized API call

Tags: api, rest

I am working with REST APIs in PHP for an iphone app. I am wondering that how can I block calls from sources other than the iphone app. How does server know that it is a call from a valid soure?

Comment: You can use API key based approach along with $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to check for browser. This are very basic steps for security

Comment: There is no perfect way , You can have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847842/is-there-a-way-to-detect-from-which-source-an-api-is-being-called

Answer (score 0):

You can't with 100% certainty block requests that are not made from a phone. If a public client has access to an API, then you can also fake it.