# Mobile App or Browser detection using ASP.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenario where I have to detect from where my **ASP.Net Web Api** is getting consumed. That is from Browser (Mobile Browser or Desktop/Laptop browser doesn't matter) or from Mobile App (IOS/Andriod or Windows APP).

I tired using `Request.Browser.IsBrowser` but it seems this detect weather its Mobile browser or not, but my situation is different. Also I tried to google but almost all the solution I found tells about detecting mobile browser not the App.

Any help is heartily appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect from which source an API is being called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847842/is-there-a-way-to-detect-from-which-source-an-api-is-being-called)

Answer (score 1):

There is no full-proof solution that you can use here to be honest. I'd suggest looking at [Is there a way to detect from which source an API is being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847842/is-there-a-way-to-detect-from-which-source-an-api-is-being-called) as it is mentioned in the aforementioned comment.

You can always look for user-agent and referrer field but none of them are mandatory ones. And it can harder especially if someone else is making the client for your server. :)